# How to make UIScrollView occupy screen height when UITableView at the bottom is hidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` that has two child elements: a `UIScrollView` on the upper half (which contains two `UILabel`s), and a `UITableView` at the bottom. This is basically a dictionary and the purpose of the scroll view is to display the word and definition, and the table view for displaying the related words. Not all words in my dictionary have a related words array associated to them, so I hide the `UITableView` when that array is empty.

However, I can't get the `UIScrollView` to fill the entire parent view when the `UITableView` is hidden. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
- (void)updateUIWithWord:(NSString *)theWord
           andDefinition:(NSString *)theDefinition
    andRelatedWordsArray:(NSArray *)theRelatedWordsArray {
    self.navigationItem.title = theWord;
    self.word.text = theWord;
    self.definition.text = theDefinition;
    self.relatedWordsArray = theRelatedWordsArray;

    if (![relatedWordsArray count]) {
        relatedWordsTableView.hidden = YES;

        // set the UITableView's width and height to 0 just to be sure
        // I feel this isn't needed though
        CGRect relatedWordsTableViewFrame;
        relatedWordsTableViewFrame.size = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        relatedWordsTableView.frame = relatedWordsTableViewFrame;

        // then make the scroll view occupy the remaining height;
        // that is, the self.view's actual height
        CGRect scrollViewFrame;
        scrollViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        scrollViewFrame.size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        scrollView.frame = scrollViewFrame;
    }
}
```

Simply put, this doesn't work. For any word that has no related words and a very long definition, the scroll view simply occupies the same amount of height even with the table view gone. Help?

**ADD**: I tried fixing the constraints in the `UIScrollView` to make it relative to the top of the `UITableView` instead of having a fixed height, but that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Have you made sure all `IBOutlet`s are connected?

Comment: Yup, all the IBOutlets are connected correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approached the problem in a different way. I made the `UIScrollView` occupy the whole screen and put the `UITableView` inside it, below my two labels, with scrollling disabled. Now I can just hide and show it.

Answer (score 1):

You have an "if" and an "else". Only *one* of those is going to execute. So when the "if" part runs and `relatedWordsTableView.hidden` is set to YES, the table view is hidden but nothing else happens. The "else" part isn't running so nothing is happening.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I made that mistake. Moved everything from the else block to the if block and deleted the else altogether. Still doesn't work though.

Comment: So now what does happen? (And again, are you *sure* this code is even running?)